# Create object which has nested orderDict

Tags: python, django, api, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

my store_categories_data has a nested orderDict like below

```
store_categories_data 
OrderedDict([('product', OrderedDict([('image', OrderedDict([('image', <InMemoryUploadedFile: bag.jpg (image/jpeg)>)])), 
('name_of_product', 'Ladies Pink Bag'), ('description', 'description'), ('price', Decimal('1600')), ('active', True)])), 
('store_category', 'BAGS')])
```

I want to pass all the product information like Image, Name, Description etc. But there is 3 orderDict.
How can i pass value to get_or_create() for creating store_categories object?

**My code**

```
class ProductSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    image = ProductImageSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields=('id','image','name_of_product','description','price','active',)

class StoreCategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializers()
    class Meta:
        model = StoreCategory

class StoreCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    store_categories = StoreCategorySerializer()
    merchant = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields=("id",
                "merchant",
                "store_categories",
                "name_of_legal_entity",
                "pan_number",
                "registered_office_address",
                "name_of_store",
                "store_contact_number",
                "store_long",
                "store_lat",
                "store_start_time",
                "store_end_time",
                "store_off_day",
                )
    def create(self,validated_data):
        store_categories_data = validated_data.pop('store_categories')
        merchant_data = validated_data.pop('merchant')
        for merchantKey, merchantVal in merchant_data.items():
            try:
                merchant,created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=merchantVal)
                print('merchant',merchant)
                print(type(merchant))
                validated_data['merchant']=merchant
                store = Store.objects.create(**validated_data)
                print('__________________________________')
                image = store_categories_data["product"].pop("image")
                image_instance = ProductImage(**image)
                print('image_instance',image_instance)
                product = store_categories_data["product"]
                print('product creation returns',product['name_of_product'])
                product_instance = Product(
                                            image=image_instance,
                                            name_of_product=product['name_of_product'],
                                            description=product['description'],
                                            price=product['price'],
                                            active=product['active']
                                        )
                print('product_instance',product_instance)
                store_category = store_categories_data['store_category']
                print('store_category',store_category)
                store_category = StoreCategory(product=product_instance, store_category=store_category)
                print('store category instance',store_category)
                return store
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise NotFound('not found')
```

**Models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name_of_legal_entity = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pan_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    registered_office_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_of_store = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    store_off_day = MultiSelectField(choices=DAY, max_length=7, default='Sat')
    store_categories = models.ManyToManyField('StoreCategory',blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    image = models.ForeignKey('ProductImage',blank=True,null=True)
    name_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')

    @property
    def imageName(self):
        return str(os.path.basename(self.image.name))


class StoreCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="store_category")
    store_category = models.CharField(choices=STORE_CATEGORIES, default='GROCERY', max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the nesting in your OrderedDict maps to foreign key relationships in a relational database, you just need to explicitly create all 3 records in order, from the inside out. Something like the below should be enough to carry it the rest of the way.

Note: unpacking dicts to keyword args with `**` only works for newer versions of python >= `Python3.5`.

```
image = store_categories_data["product"].pop("image")
image_instance = Image(**image)
product = store_categories_data["product"]
product_instance = Product(image=image_instance, product=product)
store_category = store_categories_data['store_category']
store_category = StoreCategory(product=product_instance, store_category=store_category)
```

Comment: i get this error TypeError: 'product' is an invalid keyword argument for this function. Error is on the line product_instance = Product(image=image_instance, product=product)

Comment: I updated my code with the code you provided. Now i get an error 'Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `product` on serializer `StoreCategorySerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `ManyRelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'product'.' while trying to post.

Comment: Categories and Product are not saved to database due to above error.

Comment: should I save product_instance, image_instance and store_category like product_instance.save() right after instantiation?